# Column name not found, probably because 'Latin-1' character recognized as utf-8

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, iso-8859-1

I am using Python 2.7 on Jupyter Notebook using Pandas library, and I am facing the following issue:

I have a dataset which contains characters with accents, to extract the data from the .csv I have written the following code:

```
datafile = pd.read_csv("exportacionEmitidas.csv", delimiter=";", 
encoding='latin-1', low_memory=False)
```

These are the columns that I get, which look fine to me:

```
Nº Serie + Nº Factura
Ejercicio
Periodo
Fecha Expedición
Fecha Operacion 
NIF Destinatario
Nombre o Razón Social Destinatario
```

However, when I try to make a new dataframe with only some of the columns I get the following annoying message:

```
  datafile[["Nº Serie + Nº Factura","Fecha Expedición"]]
KeyError: "['N\\xc2\\xba Serie + N\\xc2\\xba Factura' 'Fecha Expedici\\xc3\\xb3n'] not in index"
```

I wouldn't like to select the columns by its column index because I would like to avoid to make any mistake in the event that the order of the columns changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column names are *Unicode objects*, not byte strings. Use Unicode literals (prefixed with `u`) to address them:

```
datafile[[u"Nº Serie + Nº Factura", u"Fecha Expedición"]]
```

You can see this when echoing all of the column names:

```
>>> datafile.columns
Index([u'Nº Serie + Nº Factura', u'Ejercicio', u'Periodo', u'Fecha Expedición',
       u'Fecha Operacion', u'NIF Destinatario',
       u'Nombre o Razón Social Destinatario'],
      dtype='object')
```

Each of the column names is echoed using the same `u'...'` string literal syntax.

Note that for you to be able to use non-ASCII characters in such strings, you must [declare a codec at the top of your Python source file](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/):

```
# coding: UTF-8
# The above states this source file is saved using UTF-8.
```

You may want to move to Python 3. Python 3 is more fully Unicode-aware, and Python 2 will no longer be supported in 18 months time.